# Using django fields validation for external values

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I have model with one field(this is synthetic example):

```
model Tank:
      oxygen = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
          _("Oxygen %"),
          help_text="%",
          default=21,
          validators=[MinValueValidator(21.0), MaxValueValidator(50.0)],
          null=True,
      )
```

And I parse some files with data. I want to validate input data before write it model instance. Something like this

```
oxygen = get_raw_data()
Tank.oxygen.validate(oxygen) # this is wrong I know :)
# if value is valid do something
# else do something
```

What should I write instead of Tank.oxygen.validate(oxygen)?
I can duplicate validation logic or validate data when save model instance, but maybe somebody know better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually create an instance with the data, then call [`full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) on it:

```
my_tank = Tank(oxygen=oxygen)
my_tank.full_clean()
```

Comment: Yep, I know this way, but I want validate only one field(In real life model has more than one field) and make a decision about creating a model.

Comment: I would still do it this way - the model is not yet saved, so it doesn't matter if you throw it away. As the documentation explains, you can catch the ValidationError and inspect `e.message_dict` to see if the error happened on `oxygen`.

Comment: This is inappropriate if I have more than on field. This is ugly to call full_clean every_time and catch an exception. And I can't validate all fields one time because some fields depend from other

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to validate one field, then I suggest you use a form.Field class to do it:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

oxygen_field = forms.IntegerField(required=True, min_value=21, max_value=50)

def is_oxygen_valid(value):
    try:
        oxygen_field.clean(value)
    except ValidationError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Testing:

```
>>> is_oxygen_valid(None)
False
>>> is_oxygen_valid(11)
False
>>> is_oxygen_valid(55)
False
>>> is_oxygen_valid('hello')
False
>>> is_oxygen_valid(list())
False
>>> is_oxygen_valid(45)
True
```

I'm assuming that you are going to be validating the oxygen field first, and then deciding what to do depending on the result. You could adapt this to any other field you need. Just find the appropriate `FormField` class, and any Validators you might need, and use that instead.